# Matrix of Basis Change and of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Basically, I have 2 bases of $\mathbb{R}^4$:

$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ ;
$B' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

And the following Linear Tansformation Matrix $T : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$:

$M^{B'}_{B'}(T) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

My aim is to find the matrices $A^B_{B'}, A^{B'}_{B}, M^B_B(T)$ but I have no idea where I should begin.

My idea was to find the following matrix $A^B_{B'} = x$, such that:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Am I on the right track, any tips will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: I would say that $B$ and $B'$ are matrices. A basis of $\Bbb R^4$ is a set of four elements of $\Bbb R^4$ for which a certain property holds.

Comment: I fixed the confusion.

Comment: Can you give a definition of your notations $A_B^{B'}$ and $M_B^{B'}(T)$? In particular which basis (subscript or superscript) is taken as the basis of the domain and which is taken as the basis of the codomain?

Comment: $A^{B'}_{B}$ ist intepreted as the matrix of basis change from $B'$ to $B$, so it is $A_{B' \rightarrow B}$